# Threejs loading font using fontloader throws and error when using React

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm using the [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org/) library together with [React](https://reactjs.org/).

I've installed ThreeJS [using npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbitcontrols).

Adding images works fine - I'm importing an image in react like this:

```
import stockImage from './../../images/download.jpg';
```

and using it like this works great:

```
this.addCube(stockImage, { x:2, y:2, z:2 } );

(...)

addCube(imageUrl, aPosition) {
        //Load image as material:
        var anImageMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            map : this.textureLoader.load(imageUrl)
        });
        //Make box geometry:
        var box = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        //Create mesh:
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( box, anImageMaterial );
        //Add to scene:
        this.scene.add( cube );
        return cube;
    }
```

When trying to add text to the canvas using [this tutorial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TextGeometry).

I'm trying to import the font in react like this:

```
import helveticaRegular from './../../fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json';
```

Printing it like this looks good, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with react:

```
console.log(helveticaRegular);
```

However using the font like this throws an error:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( helveticaRegular, function ( font ) {
        var geometry2 = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
            font: font,
            size: 80,
            height: 5,
            curveSegments: 12,
            bevelEnabled: true,
            bevelThickness: 10,
            bevelSize: 8,
            bevelSegments: 5
        } );
        this.scene.add(geometry2);
    } );
```

The error is the following:

[image]

[image]

Please ignore C:/xammp/... as I'm not using xammp, but the folder naming was from when I used xammp.

Loading fonts like this using xammp, using a regular url does not produce the same error.

I don't know if the problem is due to urls or react or the FileLoader.load function in ThreeJS.

Comment: Have you tried using the font path directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FontLoader requires a URL as parameter by signature:

```
FontLoader.load ( url : String, onLoad : Function, onProgress : Function, onError : Function ) : null
```

What you are passing in is instead the imported file, thus FontLoader.load does not like it as **under the hood there will be an xhr call with an url parameter**.

May be the correct approach is to skip load phase and go with `FontLoader.parse(myImportedFont)`

**FontLoader.parse signature**

```
.parse ( json : Object ) : Font
json — The JSON structure to parse.

Parse a JSON structure and return a Font.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was unaware of the parse function and the 'under the hood' xhr call.


The following code worked:


var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        var font = loader.parse(helveticaRegular);
        var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', {
            font: font,
            size: 1,
            height: 0.1,
            curveSegments: 20
        } );
        var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xF00000 } );
        var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial );
        this.scene.add(textMesh);